# Using query string to redirect/rewrite to different internal IIS sites

Tags: iis, virtual-machines, redirect, rewrite, azure

I have an Azure VM that is hosting a web application.

The application will be accessible via the VM's IP address:

```
http://191.238.112.62
```

I want to be able to use query strings to redirect to completely different sites that are **within the local** IIS. For example:

```
http://191.238.112.62/?site=1
```

would redirect to

```
www.site1.com
```

The way I have structured IIS can be seen below:

[image]

Each site has an entry in the systems host file.

```
127.0.0.1 wwww.site1.com
127.0.0.1 wwww.site2.com
127.0.0.1 wwww.site3.com
```

There is likely a better way to achieve what I am going for here so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i would do :

First, you need to download and install the [URL Rewrite extension for IIS](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) (A reboot, so a downtime, may be required to activate the extention).

You will need to update your DNS creating A or CNAME records for other web Sites, e.g :

```
www.site1.com. IN A 191.238.112.62
www.site2.com. IN A 191.238.112.62
www.site3.com. IN A 191.238.112.62
```

You will need a main entry site that will respond to `http://191.238.112.62`. Let use the "Default Web Site" for this.
Configure the Bindings for this "Default Web Site" so that its Host Header is set to `191.238.112.62` :

[image]

You need to set the appropriate Host Header within the Binding for `site1.com` :

[image]

Enter the URL Rewrite module for "Default Web Site" and create a new rule :

[image]
[image]
[image]

You will need to uncheck "Append query string" to remove `?site=1` once redirected.
Then "Apply".

Proceed the same way for other sites `wwww.site2.com` and `wwww.site3.com`